# Can I resize a For Loop during the execution in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I resize a for loop during execution?  Here is a simplified example.

```
Sub ResizeLoop()
    last = 5
    For i = 0 To last
        Debug.Print i
        last = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

On the first pass, `i=0`, I attempt to resize `last` by setting it to 3 but it still executes all the way through to '5'.

---

Immediate Window:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

If I can't redefine the loop during execution is there another way.

Comment: It won't let you for a good reason: you shouldn't do this. Find another way to express your desired logic.

Comment: @MitchWheat Okay, that's why I'm asking.  Is there a different kind of loop or should I completely change my logic?  I don't want to use `Goto` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "to" is evaluated once at the beginning of the loop. Use `while` or `do while` instead:

```
i = 0
last = 5
do while i <= last
  Debug.Print i
  last = 3
  i = i + 1
loop
```

Comment: That make sense.  And thanks for the example of another loop that does allow me to make the change.